# Modify stored object

Tags: php

I have two classes, with one storing multiple references to the other. After I create a new instance of the second class, I might have to change properties on it later and I would like it to update all references to that object. Is there a way to make the object instances always pass by reference so that when a property gets updated in the object it also updates all other references to it?

```php
class Users {
    private $members = array();

    public function addMember($id) {
        $member = new Member($id);

        array_push($members, $member);

        return $member;
    }
}

class User {
    public $id;

    __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function addProperty($propName, $propValue) {
        $this->{$propName} = $propValue;
    }
}
```

So currently with this setup I can create a new member and add them to the members array:

```php
$users = new Users();

$user = $users->addMember(1);
```

But if I try to add a new property to the member as so:

```php
$member->addProperty("job_title", "developer");
```

The property doesn't appear in the members array because the member is not being passed by reference.

Comment: PHP 7.3: property appears in the instance itself and in the `$members` array.

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
public function addMember($id) {
    $member = new Member($id);
    ....
```

Here you create an object of class Member, but I think you want

```
    $member = new User($id);
```